# Find combinations of words using R

Tags: r, text

I'm editing some text and wondering whether I can programatically search for certain words.

These words: almost, nearly, quite, close to and very, do not work next to these words: certain, complete, dead, entire, essential and extinct.

Lets say I have this character vector:

```
text <- c("R is a very essential tool for data analysis. While it is regarded as domain specific, it is a very complete programming language. Almost certainly, many people who would benefit from using R, do not use it")
```

Can I get R to return a numeric vector, giving line numbers (or sentence numbers) where these words are placed next to each other?

Note that I've used "certainly", so ideally I would need R to search for words that contain "certain" or other words, as opposed to the whole word "certain" or other words.

Comment: Nitpick Monday:  remove the last comma.  :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `grep` for this, after splitting your text at sentence boundaries using `strsplit`:

```
stext <- strsplit(text, split="\\.")[[1]]
grep("certain", stext)
[1] 3
```

Comment: Isn't it so that the question was, how to find the sentences that contain a certain combination of words? I think that makes it a bit more tricky. Unfortunately I do not have a solution to it.

Comment: @DanielFischer, in that case it does take some grep-fu, or maybe something equivalent to `grep 'certain' | grep 'words' |grep 'combined'`

Comment: This code did it:`combo <- list("very essential", "very complete", "Almost certain")
stext <- strsplit(text, split="\\.")[[1]]
library(plyr)
laply(combo, function(x) grep(x, stext))`

Answer (score 2):

Andrie's solution is much better for your needs however I'm providing a second solution for those future searchers looking to parse transcripts.

```
library(qdap)
stext <- c("R is a very essential tool for data analysis. While it is regarded 
    as domain specific, it is a very complete programming language. Almost 
    certainly, many people who would benefit from using R, do not use it.")

dat <- sentSplit(data.frame(dialogue=stext), "dialogue")
with(dat, termco(dialogue, tot, "certain"))

##   tot word.count  certain
## 1 1.1          9        0
## 2 2.2         14        0
## 3 3.3         14 1(7.14%)
```

Note that punctuation is important and I needed to add in the missing period on the last sentence.

To get a vector of which sentences contain "certain":

```
which(with(dat, termco(dialogue, tot, "certain"))$raw$certain > 0)
## [1] 3
```